# What is this stray error in this program?

Tags: windows-10

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("addition of two numbers\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    c = a + b;
    printf("%d", c, \n);
    printf("subtraction of two numbers\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    c = a - b;
    printf("%d", c \n);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
 9   2  C:\Users\Yash\Documents\c.3.cpp  [Error] stray '\' in program
13   2  C:\Users\Yash\Documents\c.3.cpp  [Error] stray '\' in program
C:\Users\Yash\Documents\c.3.cpp    In function 'int main()':
 9  17  C:\Users\Yash\Documents\c.3.cpp  [Error] 'n' was not declared in this scope
13  17  C:\Users\Yash\Documents\c.3.cpp  [Error] expected ')' before 'n'
```

Comment: Your error messages are quite clear. Check your `printf()`s.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score -1):

Two of your `printf()` commands:

```
printf("%d",c,\n);
```

and

```
printf("%d",c \n);
```

are missing quotes around the newline characters (and a comma in one). They should look like this:

```
printf("%d \n",c);
```

Comment: Shouldn't **printf("%d",c,"\n");** instead be **printf("%d \n",c);**?  Of course the entire question is out of scope here at Super User.